# Need to add elements of two array together

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

Adding two integer array elements

```
if array1 = {0,0,0,0,9,9,9,9}—————> 00009999
and 
array2 = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}————————> 00000001 

adding the two arrays together should result in 10000 being in array1, since 9999 + 1 = 10000

therefore, the result should be 
array1 = {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0}
```

Does anyone know how to write a code for this? I was trying to use a while loop which didn't work effectively within another for loop. Fairly new to coding and stack overflow, any help will be appreciated!

CODE THAT I TRIED
Note: both arrays will have the same number of elements, they were initialized with the same size

```
int length = sizeof(array1)/sizeof(array1[0]);
for(int i = length; i>0; i--){
    if(array1[i-1] + array2[i-1] < 10){
        array1[i-1] += array2[i-1];
    }else{
        array1[i-1] = array1[i-1] + array2[i-1] - 10;
        if(array1[i-2]!=9){
            array1[i-2]++;
        } else{
            int j = i-2;
            while(j == 9){
                array1[j] = 0;
                j--;
            }
            array1[j-1]++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide your code up to this point. We aren't here to write the entire code for you, but we will be happy to help with specific issues you have. For something like this, you're basically doing base10 arithmetic, so you need to traverse the arrays in reverse, do the addition, then carry over any excess digits to the next array element addition.

Comment: added what I tried!

Comment: `array1[i-2]` is a dangerous thing to do when `i` could be 1.

Answer (score 1):

Code below performs base10 arithmetic: you need to iterate the arrays in reverse, do the addition of i-th digit by modulo 10, then carry over any excess digits to the next array element:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a1[] = { 0,0,0,0,9,9,9,9 };
    int a2[] = { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1 };
    const int b = 10;
    int s = 0;
    for (int i = size(a1) - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        a1[i] += a2[i] + s;
        s = a1[i] / b;
        a1[i] %= b;
    }
    std::copy(a1, a1 + size(a1), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
    cout << endl;
}
```

Alternative with C arrays and transform algorithm + make_reverse_iterator looks too heavy. Variant with std::arrays looks better:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 8> a1 = { 0,0,0,0,9,9,9,9 };
    std::array<int, 8> a2 = { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1 };
    const int b = 10;
    int s = 0;
    transform(a1.rbegin(), a1.rend(), a2.rbegin(), a1.rbegin(), [b, &s](int &i, int &j)
    {
        i += j + s;
        s = i / b;
        return i % b;
    });
    copy(a1.begin(), a1.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: If your compiler's up to date you can replace `sizeof(a1) / sizeof(a1[0])` with `std::size(a1)`.

Comment: thanks for helping, unfortunately it did not end up working, not sure why. the addition for 9999 and 1 returned 9999 again.

Comment: @pr0jectgamer try copy paste from my answer. Maybe typo. It gives correct answer - try follow the code and understand how it works. for instance - first digit:  (9 + 1) % 10 == 0

Comment: @pr0jectgamer Code is correct. Also I tested it with different inputs. And not verbose.

Comment: @VladNovakovsky must be a problem with how I set up my arrays, ill keep testing it out (the arrays aren't as simple as I made them seem)

Comment: @pr0jectgamer No problem. Try it in debugger to better understand how it works.

Comment: FYI, the `main` function returns `int`.  Always.

Comment: FYI standard allows not one prototype for main - in case of main compiler returns 0 implicitly. C++ Standard, chapter 3.6.1 paragraph 5

Comment: @pr0jectgamer I made it shorter

Comment: @pr0jectgamer so how is it going?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've overcomplicated the problem a bit. Your task is to perform base 10 addition on two arrays, carrying excess digits. You can simply iterate both arrays in reverse, perform addition on the individual elements, and ensure you carry over a digit when you exceed 10.

Here is an example based on the requirements you've described. You can further abstract this as needed.

I updated this code such that the result is now in `array1`.

```
#include <iostream>


int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *argp[]){
    /* Initialize arrays and calculate array size */
    int array1[] = {0,0,0,0,9,9,9,9};
    int array2[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1};
    int array_size = sizeof(array1) / sizeof(int);

    /* Iterate the arrays in reverse */
    int carry = 0;
    for (int i = array_size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        /* Perform addition on the current elements, remembering to include the carry digit */
        int result = array1[i] + array2[i] + carry;

        /* Determine if the addition should result in another carry */
        if (result >= 10) {
            carry = 1;
        } else {
            carry = 0;
        }
        /* Store the non-carried addition result */
        array1[i] = result % 10;
    }

    /* View result */
    for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
        std::cout << array1[i];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
uint32_t decode(int array[8]){
  uint32_t multiple_of_ten=10000000;

  uint32_t result = 0;                                
  for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
    result += (array[i] * multiple_of_ten);
    multiple_of_ten = multiple_of_ten / 10;
  }
  return result;
}

int* encode(uint32_t number){
  int result[8]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

  uint32_t multiple_of_ten=10000000;
  uint32_t recent = number;

  for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
    if(recent>0 && recent / multiple_of_ten > 0)
      {
        result[i] = recent / multiple_of_ten;
        recent %= multiple_of_ten;
      }
    multiple_of_ten /= 10;
  }
    return result;
 }
```

in your case , use `encode(decode(array1) + decode(array2))`